# How to hit Like and dislike API on left and right drag of cards using KolodaView Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, gesture, koloda

I am using kolodaview for card swift like view. Everything is working fine but i stuck at one place. When user slide card left or right, API hiting for like and dislike.
For this left and right koloda given delegate method:

```
 func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, draggedCardWithPercentage finishPercentage: CGFloat, in direction: SwipeResultDirection){
 if direction == .left {

 if finishPercentage == 100.0 {
    apifordislike()
  }
 } else if direction == .right{
    apiforlike()
 }
}
```

Its working but issue is that, while swapping finishPercentage == 100.0 and hitting API, but user slowly slide the card API hitting more than one, 100.0 is repeated. I want only one hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAt index: Int, in direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
```

instead?

Otherwise, keep info about status - e.g.

...

```
var alreadyLiked: Bool = false
var alreadyDisliked: Bool = false
```

...

```
func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, draggedCardWithPercentage finishPercentage: CGFloat, in direction: SwipeResultDirection){
 if direction == .left {

 if finishPercentage == 100.0 {
    if !alreadyDisliked {
        alreadyDisliked = true
        apifordislike()
     }
  }
 } else if direction == .right{
    if !alreadyLiked {
        alreadyLiked = true
        apiforlike()
    }
 }
}
```

in your case, you might keep two variables in case someone changes it's mind to change to dislike. Also, you might want to restart flags when action is changed from liked to disliked and vice versa.

Comment: i think func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAt index: Int, in direction: SwipeResultDirection) { is the better solution thanks

Comment: how can we add image on top when dragging is going on in left or right

Comment: you can add image in begin dragging or any other similar delegate method.